# Cannot Commit , Cannot Pull , All Tortoise git tasks are ending in errors

Tags: eclipse, git, github

previously i had a repo where my java class files were pushed as well.
i learnt that for all general purposes its best to keep only source files in your git repo. so i deleted the repo and created a new one. but when i try to push the project folder onto my github repo , i get errors and it exists with error code 1.

previously i had no such issues , all push , pull and syncs went smoothly. I'm quite at a loss at what to do.

**edit :** reading Burhan Khalid's comment , i tried this , but not working

[image]
edit : 
I tried what Kvass suggested , but iv never used gitbash , and i couldnt change my directories there. i re-installed tortoisegit , did everything i could think of , but its still gives error in EVERYTHING!

**edit:** the same thing is happening with all my repositories ! :( i cannot pull , push , sync , im virtually paralysed !

please help me out here.

Comment: Do you have the remote created on github?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid this is what i get 
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: `cd f:/code/java/eclipse/javaSurfer` and then type `git remote add origin https://github.com/Suedo/Java.git` from the gitbash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the right directory?  It looks like you are in your home directory - is that where you created your repository?

Comment: No ! ill retry in the right directory , in the meantime , can you tell me how all this can be done using tortoise git ? (iv been using tortoise git since i started github , so new to this command line git interface)
Appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know anything about tortoise git - I just use git by itself.

Comment: The error message you got is one that shows up when the folder in which you are running a git command does not contain a git repository (and therefore the git command cannot be run)

Comment: Try navigating to one of the directories in which you created a git repository and run `git status`.  That command should work 100% of the time if you are in a git repo, and 0% of the time if you are not.  If the command does not work you might not be in the right directory or might not have initialized a repo yet (you need to run `git init` or `git clone`).  If it does work and then your other command produces an error, then post more details about the error that it shows.

Comment: thanks a lot for the guide :) im reinstalling git now , and ill look into the bash command set. ill be using only the git bash from now on. ill keep you posted. appreciate your help.